# AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error in AXIS2 client(JAVA)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, soap-client

I am trying to invoke webservice(SOAP1.2) using the java application hosted on TOMCAT. Have generated the clients using AXIS2. I am getting below errow when I invoke WS method.

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Cannot process
>   the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=UTF-8; action="XXXXXXXXXXXX.SearchByName"' was not the
>   expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'
>              at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
>               at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
>               at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
>               at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
>               at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>               at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>               at XXXXXXXXXXXX.SearchByName(RelmgmtTool_WebService_BANDStub.java:937)
>               at XXXXXXXXXXXX.SearchACCLServiceImpl.searchACCL(SearchACCLServiceImpl.java:281)
>               at XXXXXXXXXXXX.ACCLSearchAction.execute(ACCLSearchAction.java:392)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.ml.grci.webapp.interceptor.GcbParamInterceptor.intercept(GcbParamInterceptor.java:81)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at com.ml.grci.webapp.interceptor.SessionCheckInterceptor.intercept(SessionCheckInterceptor.java:120)
>               at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>               at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>               at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
>               at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>               at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at com.ml.framework.webapp.filter.StaticFilter.doFilterInternal(StaticFilter.java:124)
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at com.ml.framework.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:78)
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
>               at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>               at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
>               at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>               at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>               at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>               at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
>               at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>               at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at com.ml.framework.webapp.filter.TimerFilter.doFilter(TimerFilter.java:46)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>               at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Please help.

Comment: Is this the full stack trace? Looks pretty straightforward: you're sending content of an unexpected type. What did you generate the stubs with?

Comment: @kolossus yes, I understand the error.But not sure what is the content type "'application/soap+msbin1'". Also how to set this content type while generating the request.Also updated with full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to downgrade your axis soap uri?

```
stub._getServiceClient()
   .getOptions()
   .setSoapVersionURI(
               SOAP11Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI);
```